# Problem with $oauth->fetch

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", "consumer-key");
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", "consumer-secret");
$oauth = new OAuth(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$oauth->setToken('valid-token', 'valid-key');
var_dump($oauth->fetch('https://api.twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json'));
```

Whenever I load the page, instead of producing output in my browser, my browser attempts to download a blank file with the same name as the PHP script. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The general reason for WSOD (White Screen Of Death) when developing with PHP is that you are developing with error messages turned off. Configure your development server to show all error messages (or look in the error log for your server).

Comment: I down voted your answer because it seems like you didn't really read the question. There is no mention of a WSOD anywhere in the question.

Comment: What do you think the blank file that gets downloaded is? It's a WSOD transfer. It just happens to have it Content-Type header set to something that forces a download instead of a display.